How do I get a cloned linux partition to boot?
I have a dual boot system (windows and linux) and I wanted to move the image to a larger hard drive and allocate more space to both partitions.  I cloned it without any issues, my windows system boots just fine but my linux image doesn't seem to want to boot (when I chose to boot from that hard drive, it didn't give me the option for linux, it just auto booted to windows).
I assume this is because the cloned image still has the same UUID from the previous hard drive.  I'm not entirely sure how to edit the fstab file from an image I can't boot or if that's even what I should be trying to do at this time.
I think I had read somewhere the issue is likely with the grub configuration.  How would you recommend fixing this issue?  I can use blkid to get the UUIDs using the original image (it still boots to linux just fine).  Do I just edit/update the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file or would you recommend using a live image to fix the grub image (I assume with the original hard drive removed so only the clone is on the system)?
Any help/recommendations you can give me would be appreciated.  Thanks!

You can fix grub from a live usb using one of the answers to this ask ubuntu question: https://askubuntu.com/q/831216/243321  The problem is, I'm not really sure which answer is the best. I knew how to do this reliably in the preUEFI world, but I haven't had to do it in a long time.

"UUID" is not something that "comes with" a hard drive. It's just a "label" generated for a filesystem (or partition, if you are talking about "PARTUUID") upon its creation. Depending on how you cloned "stuff" (like, whether it is a full drive clone or partitions clone, or whether the "cloner" tried to be "smart" and change the UUIDs for you so that it does not conflict with stuff on the original drive but become no longer a clone), and how you installed your system, what you might be missing is stuff outside partitions, such as UEFI boot entry, or MBR boot code.)
